Avalonia 11: How to use Image defined in ResourceDictionary depended on Theme
For my Avalonia App i want to use a different Image whether the App is in light or dark mode. Therefor I have the following Styles.axaml file:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColor">#000000</SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Accent">#00adb5</SolidColorBrush>
            <ImageBrush x:Key="SomeImage" Source="/Assets/SomeImage-Light.png"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColor">#ffffff</SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Accent">#00adb5</SolidColorBrush>
            <ImageBrush x:Key="SomeImage" Source="/Assets/SomeImage-Dark.png"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    
</ResourceDictionary>

I use this in my App.axaml as follows:
<Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="SomeNamespace.App"
             RequestedThemeVariant="Default">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceInclude Source="/Accents/Styles.axaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.Styles>
        <FluentTheme>
            <FluentTheme.Palettes>
                <ColorPaletteResources x:Key="Light" RegionColor="#EEEEEE" Accent="#00ADB5"/>
                <ColorPaletteResources x:Key="Dark" RegionColor="#2b2b2b" Accent="#0D7377"/>
            </FluentTheme.Palettes>
        </FluentTheme>
    </Application.Styles>
    
</Application>

With this I can use my defined styles like this:
<SomeElement Background="{DynamicResource Accent}"/>.
But doing this for the Image does not work. Doing it as follows I get no error but the Image is also not beeing displayed: <Image Source="{DynamicResource SomeImage}"/>.
What am I doing wrong and how can I display an Image depended on the Light and Dark mode?

You should have noticed an error message like the following (for example in the Output Window in Visual Studio) when you debug the application:
Error in binding to 'Avalonia.Controls.Image'.'Source': 'Unable to convert object 'Avalonia.Media.ImageBrush' of type 'Avalonia.Media.ImageBrush' to type 'Avalonia.Media.IImage'.
This is because the Image.Source property expects an instance of a type that implements IImage, e.g. a Bitmap, but your resources are of type ImageBrush.
Change your ResourceDictionary like this:
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        ...
        <Bitmap x:Key="SomeImage">/Assets/SomeImage-Light.jpg</Bitmap>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        ...
        <Bitmap x:Key="SomeImage">/Assets/SomeImage-Dark.jpg</Bitmap>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>


Alternatively you could keep the ImageBrush resources, but then you would use them like any other Brush, i.e. for the Background or Fill property, like
<Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource SomeImage}"/>


Worked, thank you :D. Strangly though I did not receive any errors. It just didn't show any Image.

It seems that my preview is broken now. As its says: "The resource /Assets/Some-Dark.png could not be found". I guess it has something to that Avalonia cant find the Images in my Styles file? The File for the error directs me to the UserControl where I used the Dynamic Resource

Which preview do you mean? A UserControl's preview with an Image that uses the resource works well for me.

Yeah I meant the UserControl preview. I now figured out it only throws the error for one specific DynamicResource. All other work fine although they are all the same, so there should be no difference. I also now got the error on build. So not only for the preview. Seems there is indeed something wrong for this Asset

Make sure the Build Action of the image files is AvaloniaResource.

It is. I also already removed, renamed and readded the file to see if something was behaving weirdly but that didn't change anything.

Interesting. The same issue also occurs for every new Asset I include. I just added a "testimage-black-x256.png" set it to AvaloniaResource and added it to my Styles.axaml file with the key "TestImage". As long as the DynamicResource of "TestImage" is not used all is ok. But if it is used I get a Runtime Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The resource /Assets/testimage-black-x256.png" could not be found.'

Have you tried a fully qualified Avalonia Resource URI like avares://<AssemblyName>/Assets/testimage-black-x256.png?

yes but it didn't make a difference.
Here is an image of my ResourceDictionary with error: ResourceDictionary
And my File in Solution explorer: SolutionExplorer

Maybe it is this issue: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/5659. You could try to use String instead of Bitmap as resource. I will try that later today.

Found the problem... Yeah there was a " at the end of the file path (after the .png) xD. So Resource was:
<Bitmap x:Key="FileOpenImage">/Assets/fileopen-black-x256.png"</Bitmap> although it should be <Bitmap x:Key="FileOpenImage">/Assets/fileopen-black-x256.png</Bitmap>
